# Paper-tabs with links display issue

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit, page.js

I am writing a polymer single page website using page.js, just like in the polymer-starter-kit. Instead of using a paper-menu for the routing, I am using paper-tabs.

So the routing is working and everything, but I can't get the paper-tabs to look like paper-tabs anymore. They just look like links and I can't see the selection bar at the bottom.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

index.html

```
<!-- Main Toolbar -->
    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="medium-tall">
      <!-- Application name -->
      <div class="app-name">Website</div>

      <span class="space"></span>

      <!-- Toolbar icons -->
      <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>

      <!-- Application tabs -->
      <paper-tabs class="bottom" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
        <paper-tab link>
          <a data-route="home" href="{{baseUrl}}">
            <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
            <span>Home</span>
          </a>
        </paper-tab>
        <paper-tab link>
          <a data-route="artist" href="{{baseUrl}}artist">
            <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
            <span>Artist</span>
          </a>
        </paper-tab>
        <paper-tab link>
          <a data-route="teacher" href="{{baseUrl}}teacher">
            <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
            <span>Teacher</span>
          </a>
        </paper-tab>
        <paper-tab link>
          <a data-route="research" href="{{baseUrl}}research">
            <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
            <span>Research</span>
          </a>
        </paper-tab>
        <paper-tab link>
          <a data-route="contact" href="{{baseUrl}}contact">
            <iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon>
            <span>Contact</span>
          </a>
        </paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
    </paper-toolbar>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="content">
      <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
        <section data-route="home">
          <paper-material elevation="1">
            <my-greeting></my-greeting>

            <p class="subhead">You now have:</p>
            <my-list></my-list>

            <p>Looking for more Web App layouts? Check out our <a href="https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout-templates">layouts</a> collection. You can also <a href="http://polymerelements.github.io/app-layout-templates/">preview</a> them live.</p>
          </paper-material>
        </section>

        <section data-route="artist">
          <paper-material elevation="1">
            <h2 class="page-title">Users</h2>
            <p>This is the users section</p>
            <a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Addy">Addy</a><br>
            <a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Rob">Rob</a><br>
            <a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Chuck">Chuck</a><br>
            <a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Sam">Sam</a>
          </paper-material>
        </section>

        <section data-route="teacher">
          <paper-material elevation="1">
            <h2 class="page-title">User: {{params.name}}</h2>
            <div>This is {{params.name}}'s section</div>
          </paper-material>
        </section>

        <section data-route="contact">
          <paper-material elevation="1">
            <h2 class="page-title">Contact</h2>
            <p>This is the contact section</p>
          </paper-material>
        </section>
      </iron-pages>
    </div>
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you set online example of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your problem. When your click on tabs, they are not save the states of click and selected tab.

This answer will partly clarify the problem [Change URL in address bar after click on DOM element with javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029706/change-url-in-address-bar-after-click-on-dom-element-with-javascript-jquery)

In Polymer I have the same problem, but with menu items. I think your can resolve it in this way:

1). Use [app-router](https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router) instead page.js and add pushstate mode to it `mode='pushstate'`.

2). Include pushstate-anchor to your page before include the app-router `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/pushstate-anchor/pushstate-anchor.html">`. This will save all links and reloading the page will not be.

Comment: Thanks, yea I actually ended up going with app-router and got it to work. I guess page.js doesn't play nice with polymer elements?

Comment: Its works, but as far as I know now Polymer's workgroup try to create better router for Polymer. App-router now is the best variant, I think.