# Change URL in address bar after click on DOM element with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any way to change the URL in browser without reloading page after click a DOM element?

```
    $('#filter_form').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax(options);
        //change the browser URL
    });
```

Ex:

Before: `http://somepage.com/filters`

After: `http://somepage.com/filters?type=apartment`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the [history API](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-history-interface). Both [`history.pushState`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-history-pushstate) and [`history.replaceState`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-history-replacestate) let you specify a new URL, e.g.:

```
history.pushState(null, null, "filters?type=apartment");
```

The URL is resolved in the usual way.

[Browser support is good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history), other than IE9 and earlier.

Comment: Does this work on a local file? Or only on a server?

Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'Desktop/form_submit.html?type=apartment' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'Desktop/form_submit.html'.

Comment: @IonVasile: I've never tried it with a local file. A **lot** of things either don't work, or work differently, with resources loaded via the `file://` protocol; and that list varies by browser (famously, Chrome and Firefox have very different interpretations of the SOP wrt `file://` resources, for instance)..